# More accurate alternative to findline?

Tags: python, search, python-2.7

I have a list (words.txt) for which I need a method to search that is more exact than findline.

My current function (shown at the bottom) uses `findline` to search through the list. The problem is this: instead of returning an exact match, `findline` returns the first string that contains the whole word, regardless of whether there are better matches following it.

Example:
I enter 'BEES' and findline returns 'BAUBEES' because it is the first string to contain the sub-string ('BEES'). Of course, this completely ruins the function.

What I need is a function or (preferably) a built-in method that looks *alphabetically* for an exact match. So if 'BEES' is in the list (which I assure you it is), I want it to return 'BEES'. Or alternately, if 'BAUBEES' and 'BEESWAX' were the only substring matches in the list, the ideal function would return 'BEESWAX' if only because the second letter in 'BEES' is 'E' NOT 'A' (as in 'BAUBEES').

```
def iswholeword(word):
    openfile = open('/media/Gianson/Python Programs/words.txt','r')
    linz = openfile.readlines()[:]
    openfile.close()
    hit = findline(word,linz)[:]
    print 'hit', hit
    if len(hit)-1  == len(word):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r = re.compile(r"\b%s" % re.escape(word))
for line in openfile:
    hit = r.search(line)
    if hit:
        # whatever
```

Explanation: this build a regular expression from `\b` (word boundary) and the `word` under consideration, then searches for it in each `line` of the file. It finds the first word starting with `word` in the line and return an [regexp match object](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects).

Comment: Sorry, I left out the definition of findline like an idiot:

def findline(word,linz):
    for line in linz:
        if word in line:
            return line

Thanks larsmans, I'll give it a try and report back!

Comment: Ok, tried that and got three responses like this:<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xa6151e0>

Comment: def find(word, letter):
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
        index = index + 1
    return -1